# bash if statement troubles [Error==Error]: not found

Tags: bash

Everytime I run my script the following if statement gives me the error;

```
script.sh: [Error==Error]: not found
```

or

```
script.sh: [Error==-2]: not found
```

```
if ["$P1"=="$P2"];then
            echo $name
fi
```

I've tried other versions

```
    if ["$P1"=="$P2"]
            then
            echo $name
    fi
```

and

```
    if [[ "$P1" == "$P2" ]]
            then
            echo $name
fi

P1="Error"
P2="$(sed -n '1p' somefile.txt)"
```

`somefile.txt` might contain a number or a string

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spaces are significant. Use:

```
if [ "$P1" = "$P2" ]
```

#### What went wrong

When the shell sees `["$P1"=="$P2"]`, it interprets it as a single word and looks for a command that matches that word.  Since no such command exists, you get the `not found` error message.

Comment: Did exact same thing and got an ` [:` unexpected operator error.

Comment: Had to use = instead of ==. works now. Thanks